# jquery replace previous .after when the value changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#paragraphDuration").bind('keyup', function() {

   var fullDuration = $("#fullDuration").val(),
       paragraphDuration = $(this).val();

   $(this).after(function() {
       if ($(this).val() != '') {
           $(this).after(fullDuration - paragraphDuration + " min");
       } else {
           $(this).after("");
       }
   });
});
```

after i changed ("#paragraphDuration") many times , this is what i got:

[image: above code result]

this is not what i want !

how to replce previous .after when changing ("#paragraphDuration") value with new one ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite the old value. It's best to not use `.after` to set the text, just use the `.text()` method on a predefined span element or so.

So for instance:

*html*

```
<input type="text" id="paragraphDuration"><span class="textContainer"></span>
```

*js*

```
$("#paragraphDuration").bind('keyup', function() {

   var fullDuration = $("#fullDuration").val(),
       paragraphDuration = $(this).val();

   $(this).next('.textContainer').text(
     $(this).val() !== '' 
       ? (fullDuration - paragraphDuration + " min") 
       : ""
   );
});
```